# iCarousel auto scroll effect

Tags: ios, icarousel

I have two concerns to ask.

I would like this scrolling be infinite. I do not want it to stop. I am using iCarousel

My second concern is, while time is passing, scrolling gets
faster with the following code snippet. I would like to keep same speed.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     [carousel scrollByNumberOfItems:4 duration:20]
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iCarousel infinite scrolling and same scrolling speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710404/icarousel-infinite-scrolling-and-same-scrolling-speed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the latest version of iCarousel as of January 02, 2015, you could add the following code in your `ViewDidLoad` method in your `Viewcontroller`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //configure carousel
     carousel.type=iCarouselTypeCylinder;
     carousel.autoscroll=0.4;

   }
```

Comment: Yeah, you really shouldn't ever modify the iCarousel code to do this - it's a public property, just set it from within your controller as the last example shows.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That is the reason that I provided the last example. I just wanted to emphasize where auto scroll comes. By the way, thanks a lot for making this great framework available  to public.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nick and Casillas for further clarifications.

Comment: it is scrolling left. Is there any way it moves right ?

Comment: @SyedFarazHaiderZaidi just use a negative value

Answer (score 4):

Use the autoscroll property instead (just set it to the speed you want)

Comment: Hi Nick, could you please specify in detail with giving an example. which method you refer?

Comment: Based on Nick's answer (who created iCaorusel framework), I have provided an example. I hope it will help.

Comment: it is scrolling left. Is there any way it moves right ?

Answer (score 0):

if u give `negative` value it moves right to left (the code like this)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         carousel.type=iCarouselTypeCylinder;
         carousel.autoscroll= - 0.4;
     }
```